# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8332: Connection refused

Tags: laravel-8, cryptocurrency

how to solve this problem under laravel? Help me

cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8332: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:8332/wallet/1

when creating a wallet in an application for the blockchain.
documentation
[la documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html/)

Thanks

I tried to read the documentation but without any result or change the ports

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out a way. Change from localhost:8332 to your Windows IP: IPv4: 192.168.XX.X:8332. It was the only way that worked it out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).